# ADB Over network on a Hotspot serve by Mac Machine

Tags: macos, mac, android, hotspot

I have a Windows machine and an android phone connected to a Hotspot served by a Mac machine.

I am unable to ping the IP Address of Android phone from Windows machine.

I am trying to use ADB Over network on a Hotspot serve by Mac Machine with no success.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: We'll need a bit more detail about the configuration to be able to give an answer.

Comment: @Chenmunka does it matter ? anyway running Yosemite, core I7, 8GB, iMac